# Char array comparison issue

Tags: c, arrays, string, comparison

I have this type of array: char ArrayPalavra[100][200];

And i'm feeding like that:

```
pchPalavra = strtok(palavras," ");

while (pchPalavra != NULL)
{
    tamanhoArrayPalavra++;
    strcpy(ArrayPalavra[i++], pchPalavra);
    pchPalavra = strtok (NULL, " ");
}
```

I'm writing this array with words, like "this", "is", "a", "test".
The problem is, if i put that array in a for for comparison with a word, that dont match.

```
for(int i = 0; i < tamanhoArrayPalavra; i++)
{
    if("this" == ArrayPalavra[i])
    {
        printf("Work!");
    }
}
```

But in test, if i print the ArrayPalavra[i], they come with "this". why using iteration doenst work ? I'm using C language.

Comment: You cannot use the equal sign `==` to compare strings use [strcmp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`strcmp()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) for string comparison, like this:

```
#include <string.h> // include the header that provides the methods for strings

// 'ArrayPalavra[i]' should be NULL terminated!
if(strcmp("this", ArrayPalavra[i]) == 0)
{
    printf("Equal\n");
}
```

Do not forget that strings in C should be NULL terminated!

Answer (score -1):

`==` operator doesn't work in C for strings. It will compare the pointers' memory addresses, which will always be false. you need to import the `strings.h` header and then you do

```
strcmp("this", ArrayPalavra[i]);
```